# Randomly choosing a number and then the dealer picks $20$ from the same set

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

I am reading the following problem:

> In the game of one-spot keno, a card is purchased for $\$1$. It allows
> a player to choose a number from $1$ to $80$. A dealer then chooses
> $20$ numbers at random. If the player's number is among those chosen,
> the player is paid $3.2$ but does not get to keep the $1$ paid to play
> the game. Find the expected value of a $\$1$ bet. Describe what it
> means

My approach:

| Outcome | Gain or Loss | Probability |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Win | $\$3.2 - \$1 = \$2.2$ (winning minus cost for the ticket) | $\frac{1}{80}$ |
| Lose | $\$-1$ | $\frac{79}{80}$ |

My reasoning is that the probability that the person picks the winning number is $1$ out of the $80$ available. The probability to lose is $79$ out of $80$.
The expected value is: $(2.2 \cdot \frac{1}{80}) - \frac{79}{80} = -\$0.96$

which means that on average the person is expected to lose -$\$0.96$ per game in the long run.

The answer though says: -$\$0.2$

I think that because I am not using the $20$ numbers as part of my formula is the error here, although I don't really understand how to include them since, the person **first** picked a number between $[1,80]$ and **then** the dealer picked $20$ numbers.

Could someone help me understand this?

Comment: After you'e picked your number, you could become the first winning number, or the second one, up to the twentieth.  So you have $20/80$ chance of winning and $60/80$ of losing.

Comment: @Empy2: `So you have 20/80 chance of winning` how do I have $20/80$ if I only choose $1$ number?

Comment: You have the same number twenty times, every time the dealer picks a number, and they add up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say the player has purchased a card numbered $n \  (1 \leq n \leq 80$).

Now dealer chooses $20$ numbers out of $1-80$. We need to find probability that number $n$ is in those $20$ cards.

As the card numbered $n$ must be in one of the $20$ numbers chosen, the probability is simply,

$\displaystyle \frac{20 \choose 1}{80 \choose 1} = \frac{1}{4}$

Alternatively look at it this way. Favorable outcomes are when the dealer chooses number $n$ and chooses $19$ numbers out of rest $79$.

$\displaystyle \frac{79 \choose 19}{80 \choose 20} = \frac{20}{80} = \frac{1}{4}$

So expected gain is $ \displaystyle \frac{1}{4} \times 3.2 + \frac{3}{4} \times 0 - 1 = -0.2$

So in fact the player is expected to lose $ \$ 0.20$ playing the game.

Comment: So then my error is only in the probability of winning? The probability of losing is 7980 and the 20 picked numbers have no side effect on that?

Comment: @Jim probability of losing is $\frac{60}{80} = \frac{3}{4}$ or $1 - \frac{1}{4}$. As in that case, $n$ is one of the $60$ numbers that the dealer did not choose.

Comment: $P(L) = 1 - P(W)$.

Comment: Does $\displaystyle \frac{20 \choose 1}{80 \choose 1}$  mean choose the winning number from the $20$ picked over choose the winning number from the total $80$?

Comment: yes it means the player purchases a number which is from $20$ winning numbers picked by dealer over a number from the total $80$.

Comment: I don't understand what you meany by "$20$ winning numbers". Only $1$ number can win right? Could you please elaborate a bit more because I am confused on the logic there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124857/discussion-between-math-lover-and-jim).

Comment: I am in the chat!

Comment: I am online in the chat

Answer (score 0):

For you to win the bet the dealer's pick must include $1$ winning number (the one you picked) and $19$ other numbers. The probability of that is
$$\frac{\binom11\binom{79}{19}}{\binom{80}{20}}=\frac14$$
This may be derived in a simpler way, since for the purposes of calculating the probability of winning it does not matter whether you or the dealer moves first – neither action influences the other. By letting the dealer roll the winning numbers first, and then you choosing a number, the probability of winning is clearly $\frac{20}{80}=\frac14$. From there the expected gain can be computed to be negative $20$ cents as stated.

Comment: So then my error is only in the probability of winning? The probability of losing is $\frac{79}{80}$ and the $20$ picked numbers have no side effect on that?

Comment: @Jim Yes.${}{}{}$ The probability of losing is $\frac{60}{80}$.

Comment: What does $1 \choose 1$ mean? Choose $1$ winning number out of $1$ number? Could you please break down that formula? I think the denominator is choose $20$ numbers of $80$ for the sample space, but I am getting confused with how to understand the nominator

Comment: @Jim This is the hypergeometric distribution. Choose 1 of your number out out of 1, 19 not-your-numbers out of 20, out of 80 choose 20.

Comment: Does this mean that to understand the answer fully I need to read about "hypergeometric distribution"? Is it something that I could encounter it often e.g. as fundamental as expected values?

Answer (score 0):

If the dealer picks $20$ out of the $80$ numbers, then one-fourth of the numbers have been selected. Each number is equally likely to be selected, meaning that the probability of the dealer selecting your number is $1/4$.

Comment: The dealer selects one-fourth of the numbers, but from those the dealer picks one more as the winner. How does that calculate as 1/4?

Comment: @Jim: Why does the dealer pick more than one as a winner? That wasn’t clear to me from the question.

Comment: I phrased it poorly and I confused you. I meant to say that the dealer picks 20 numbers. And those may have the number the player selected as part of those or may not

Comment: @Jim: Yes, that's right. That doesn't contradict what I've written though. You're right that the dealer either selects the player's number or not, but the dealer only selects one-fourth of the numbers. Hence, the player's number has a $1/4$ chance of being chosen.